# datagridview remove cell background color c#

Tags: c#

For each row,it counts all cells with a background color of YellowGreen and associates the row name(i.e.the name in my example is,“teachers“ and „students“ as indicated in the column with title“DD“). It is possible to remove or disable the background color? It does simply not work. Can you help me please? I tried the following code:

dgv.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = dgv.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;

```
var dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.Columns.Add("s1", "s1");
dgv.Columns.Add("s2", "s2");
dgv.Columns.Add("s3", "s3");
dgv.Columns.Add("s4", "s4");
dgv.Columns.Add("s5", "s5");
dgv.Columns.Add("s6", "s6");
dgv.Columns.Add("DD", "DD");    
dgv.Rows.Add("Fiona", "Lila", "Ben", "Ella", "Leon", "John", "Teachers");
dgv.Rows.Add("Jack", "Luke", "Fiona", "Sophie", "Lila", "Leon", "Students");
dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
dgv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
dgv.Rows[0].Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
dgv.Rows[0].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
dgv.Rows[2].Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
dgv.Rows[2].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
dgv.Rows[2].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;

var sums = dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(row => new { 
        Name = row.Cells[row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().First(cell => cell.OwningColumn.HeaderText == "DD").ColumnIndex].Value , 
        Count = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Count(c => c.Style.BackColor == Color.YellowGreen)})
    .ToList();

var lb = new ListBox();
sums.ForEach(s => lb.Items.Add($"{s.Name}: {s.Count}"));
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just remove these code lines:

```
dgv.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = dgv.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;

dgv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
dgv.Rows[0].Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
dgv.Rows[0].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
dgv.Rows[2].Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
dgv.Rows[2].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
dgv.Rows[2].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
```